# Convert String to Tree Structure

Tags: xslt

I'm very new to xslt (1.0), anyhow I want to start with some difficult ....

Given is a source XML with a stringvalue "432565" (`<Line>432565</Line>`)

Output should be an XML

```
<element id="1">4</element>
<element id="2">43</element>
<element id="3">432</element>
<element id="4">4325</element>
<element id="5">43256</element>
<element id="6">432565</element>
```

Currently I've a recursive template

```
 <xsl:template match="Line" name="letters">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="$text != ''">
      <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($text, 1, 1)"/>
      <element>
        <xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
      </element>
      <xsl:call-template name="letters">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $letter)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

that return

```
<element>4</element>
<element>3</element>
<element>2</element>
<element>5</element>
<element>6</element>
<element>5</element>
```

I feel that the solution is not far away, but as mentioned, I'm very new to xslt.

Answer (score 1):

As well as passing in the text as a parameter, you could also pass in a "length" parameter, which starts at 1, and then is incrementing by 1 for each call of the template. This can then be used to determine the length of the text string to output.

Try this template instead

```
 <xsl:template match="Line" name="letters">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="length" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$length &lt;= string-length($text)">
      <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($text, 1, $length)"/>
      <element id="{$length}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$letter"/>
      </element>
      <xsl:call-template name="letters">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length + 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in creating the `id` attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to walk backwards:

```
<xsl:template match="Line" name="dwindle">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="$text">
        <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length($text)" />
        <xsl:call-template name="dwindle">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring($text, 1, $length - 1)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <element id="{$length}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```